# Display and mask onclick Marker Google Map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, dictionary

i have a problem with Google Map.

I have three marker on my google map.

At the first view, i want display one marker.

if i click on the btn2 or btn3, i want to display it and mask the marker 1.
An the same if i click on btn1 when the btn2 or btn3 is display.

I want to custom my marker with a specific url too.

This is my code Js.

```
    var locations = [
      ['Homexpo', 44.89589669999999, -0.5713743999999679, 3],
      ['Biganos', 44.640044, -0.9629101000000446, 2],
      ['Siege social', 44.8864352, -0.6952949999999873, 1]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('ggmap-offre'), {
      zoom: 9,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.795454, -1.147783000000004),
      scrollwheel: false,
      draggable: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });
    }
```

and this is my code HTML

```
    <div id="ggmap-offre"></div>
    <div id="bloc-txt-ggmap">
        <h4>Nos <span class="gras">adresses</span></h4>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <a class="clik-map btn1" href="#"><div class="info-multi-lieu">
            Homexpo
            <p class="cp">33300 Bordeaux Lac</p>
        </div></a>
        <a class="clik-map btn2" href="#"><div class="info-multi-lieu">
            BIGANOS
            <p class="cp">134 avenue de la côte d'argent<br/>33380 Biganos</p>
        </div></a>
        <a class="clik-map btn3" href="#"><div class="info-multi-lieu">
            Siège social
            <p class="cp">1, rue Alfred Musset<br/>33160 Saint-Médard-en-Jalles</p>
        </div></a>
    </div>
```

I wish you can help me.

This is the URL : http://pier17.fr/beta-sanem/nous-contacter.html

Thank you so much and have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code:

```
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });
}
```

so, if you want to make some other maker, marker parameter will be located in for loop code.

I suggest this code... but i did not test it!

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm really bad in Js and Google Map.

What's the difference? :s

Comment: i think... if marker is located in "for loop code". new 3 marker will be made in memory so you can get 3 marker object. but if maker is located outside from "for loop code". marker is only one in memory. so you get only one marker object...